# How to download binary file using wxwidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I found this code snippet for downloading file:

```
wxURL url(wxT("http://www.example.com/file.txt"));
if(url.GetError()==wxURL_NOERR)
{
    wxString htmldata;
    wxInputStream *in = url.GetInputStream();

    if(in && in->IsOk())
    {
        wxStringOutputStream html_stream(&htmldata);
        in->Read(html_stream);
        wxLogMessage(htmldata);
    }
    delete in;
}
```

But fistly it just logs content of file and only for text-files. But I need to download *.exe file to execute it later. So I need to adapt this code to work with binary data, and save this data to file on the disk. Too many Streams used here for my understanding what's going on here. Please help.

Comment: Did you try with [wxFileOutputStream](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_output_stream.html) instead of string output ?

Comment: Yes, file is downloaded, but not executable win32 application

Comment: Reading a file over the network is the same no matter what kind of file it is, data is just data. The big difference is what you do with the data on the receiving side, for example you can't use e.g. `wxStringOutputStream` or log the data as text unless the data actually *is* text. I don't know anything about the WX network classes, but if you search around the online manual pages I'm sure you could find a stream class to handle arbitrary data, then it's just a matter of writing it to disk instead of logging the data, and here the important part is to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: Did you use ` wxFileOutputStream` with a `wxFile` (binary by default), and not with a `wxFFile`(Text) ?

Answer (score 1):

I have written below code previously...
This will work fine to download binary files in any platforms.

```
 /** START */
 // ex) ht tp://mysite.com/mypath.jpg
 wxString path   = wxT("/mypath.jpg");
 wxString server = wxT("mysite.com");

 wxHTTP http; 
 http.SetHeader(_T("Content-type"), contentType); 
 http.SetTimeout(10);

 // wxString imageFilePath = wxT("/tmp/image.jpg");
 wxFileOutputStream output(imageFilePath);
 wxDataOutputStream store(output);

 if (http.Connect(server, 80)) 
 {
  wxInputStream *stream;
  stream = http.GetInputStream(path);

  if (stream == NULL) 
  {
       output.Close();
  } 
  else 
  {
       unsigned char buffer[1024];
       int byteRead;

       // receive stream
       while (!stream->Eof()) 
       {
        stream->Read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        store.Write8(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        byteRead = stream->LastRead();
        if (byteRead <= 0) 
        {
         break;
        }
       }

       output.Close();
  }
 } 
 else 
 {
  output.Close();
 }
```